# How i will show my deactivated commandLink in UI

Tags: visualforce

I have built a pagination, in my page i have used two commandLink(Next|Previous) and according to the no of record size thi link will activate /deactivate.
Now My issue is if i am on firstPage it's only Showing me the NEXT link in enable mode ,not showing the Previous Link but requirement is to show both the link(nextLink in active mode , previous in deactive mode), and simultaniously it will change accordding to the record size.

my vfpage:-

Here is your Document Distribution List

```
    <apex:pageblock id="pbId" >

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
            <apex:pageblock >  

     <apex:pageblockButtons location="Top">
     <apex:commandButton value="Processed" action="{!clickMe}" />
      </apex:pageblockButtons> 

      <div align="right">

      <!--<apex:commandLink value="Previous" action="{!Setcon.Previous}" onclick="if{!(Setcon.hasPrevious)} {return true;}" id="khillan" />-->
             <apex:commandLink value="Previous" action="{!Setcon.Previous}" rendered="{!(Setcon.hasPrevious)}" reRender="myform" />

                   &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <apex:commandLink value="Next" action="{!Setcon.Next}" rendered="{!(Setcon.hasNext)}" reRender="myform" />
     </div> 

        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Contact}" var="cc" id="test"  >

                    <apex:column headerValue="Choose Contact">

                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cc.bool}"/> </apex:column>

                    <apex:column value="{!cc.con.Name}"/>

          </apex:pageblocktable>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">

                     </apex:pageBlockButtons>

             <div align="right">
            <apex:commandLink value="Previous" action="{!Setcon.Previous}" rendered="{!(Setcon.hasPrevious)}" reRender="myform" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <apex:commandLink value="Next" action="{!Setcon.Next}" rendered="{!(Setcon.hasNext)}" reRender="myform" />
            </div>

            <apex:actionFunction name="refreshPageSize" action="{!refreshPageSize}" status="fetchStatus" reRender="pbId"/>
                <apex:selectList value="{!size}"  multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="refreshPageSize();">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!ContactsTables}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:outputText >{!(setCon.pageNumber * size)+1-size}-{!IF((setCon.pageNumber * size)>noOfRecords, noOfRecords,(setCon.pageNumber * size))} of {!noOfRecords}</apex:outputText>
            </apex:pageblock>

            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!display}">
                    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!selectedList}" var="w"  columns="2" >
                    <apex:column value="{!w.Name}"/>

                </apex:pageblocktable>
           </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:pageblock>

</apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for pagination : where **isFirst** and **isLast** are the boolean variables which indicates the first and last page

```
<table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="33.33%">
            </td>
            <td width="33.33%" align="center">
                <div class="paginator"> 
                    <span class="prevNextLinks">
                        <apex:outputText rendered="{!isFirst}">
                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <img src="/s.gif" class="firstoff" alt="First Page"/>
                            </span>

                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <img src="/s.gif" class="prevoff" alt="Previous"/>Previous
                            </span>
                        </apex:outputText>

                        <apex:outputText rendered="{!!isFirst}">
                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!firstPage}" reRender="pageSection">
                                    <img src="/s.gif" class="first" alt="First Page"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </span>

                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!previousPage}"  reRender="pageSection">
                                    <img src="/s.gif" class="prev" alt="Previous"/>Previous
                                </apex:commandLink> 
                            </span>
                        </apex:outputText>

                        <apex:outputText rendered="{!isLast}">
                            <span class="prevNext">
                                Next<img src="/s.gif" class="nextoff" title="Next" alt="Next" />
                            </span>

                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <img src="/s.gif" class="lastoff" title="Last Page" alt="Last Page" />
                            </span>
                        </apex:outputText>

                        <apex:outputText rendered="{!!isLast}">
                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!nextPage}" reRender="pageSection">
                                    Next<img src="/s.gif" class="next" title="Next" alt="Next" />
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </span>

                            <span class="prevNext">
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!lastPage}" reRender="pageSection">
                                    <img src="/s.gif" class="last" title="Last Page" alt="Last Page" />
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </span>
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="33.33%" align="right">
                Page<input type="text"  value="{!intPageNumber}" id="textBx"  onchange="goToPageNumberAF(document.getElementById('textBx').value);" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" style="width:40px;height:12px"/> of {!intTotalPages}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use commandButton instead of command link.It will work fine.And
give a condition to disable button depend on your record size.So button will show but it will be disabled.Like

<
apex:commandButton status="status" reRender="pb" value="<" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/
>

Comment: If you want code then I can give you

Comment: my issue is on commandLink.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Salesforce and Apex then you can explore [apex-Lang](https://code.google.com/archive/p/apex-lang/) project, It has awesome library to write pagination/SOQL Builder/CSV Parser etc..